# How to view how my website content looks across devices

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a general question regarding css:

i want to add media queries to adapt to different screen sizes. But how do I know what values to give the different queries if i cant see it on the respective screen size?
is there a way to do preview how my content will look?

Comment: You can use Toogle Device Toolbar for different Screen sizes in Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter **Chrome's** (or **Opera's**) **dev tools** and activate **Device Mode** to simulate different screen sices. I like to use the responsive mode that allows you to drag and resize to check the behavior across different sizes and the **Media Query ruler** that shows you the CSS break points.

[image: Chrome devices]

Other browsers have similar tools, like Firefox's **'Responsive Design Mode**' or Edge's '**Emulation**', both accessed through **Inspect Element**.

Yet this simulations don't guarantee to behave 100% like the devices.

Answer (score 3):

You can google chrome's inspect tool by clicking right on a webpage and click the little phone icon in the top left corner to view your website on various device sizes.

Comment: Use this and it's the preferred method and it's built into chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like this, to test it in different devices size and resolution.

```
https://screenfly.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers have device emulators in their Developer Tools. For Chrome you can find the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

For even more cross browser/device testing you can use: https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots

Still nothing beats setting up a device lab, where you can physically test on some of the most popular devices.

Hope that helps,